# Callback doesn't receive the updated version of state even when it fires well after state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using a functional component. I'm aware `setColor` changes the value of `color` asynchronously. However, my callback function doesn't receive the updated version of `color` (blue) even when it executes well after `color` has been updated. Here's an abstract version of my code:

```js
let [color, setColor] = useState("red");

useEffect(() => {
  setColor("blue");
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(color);
  }, 5000)
}, []);
```

(here's a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-cherry-17ip2?file=/src/App.js)

My only guess is that the `setColor` function almost creates a new `color` variable & `console.log` is stuck referencing the old `color`.

---

*Troubleshooting*

1. I'm aware a secondary `useEffect` has the potential to execute my callback when state changes. However, this is inconvenient because I'm right in the middle of complex logic where I only want the callback to execute under certain conditions.
2. I'm also aware `useRef` variables update pretty much immediately and so that'd be an alternative.

---

Nevertheless, the question still stands: why isn't the updated value of `color` being logged & is there anything I could do in the primary `useEffect` to access the latest version of `color` state?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: it is updated to blue, but as Quentin explained in his answer you are logging the state value from the render when the setTimeout was instantiated. just move the `console.log` out of the useEffect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `setColor` changes the state.
2. The change in stage makes the Function Component execute again
3. The new invoke of the Function Component reruns `let [color, setColor] = useState("red");`
4. This assigns the current state of `color` to the `color` variable.
5. Time passes
6. The arrow function passed to `setTimeout` runs. This has [closed over](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) the **previous** `color` variable which was assigned the **old** state.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin I've just updated the snippet to include the empty array at the end of `useEffect` I forgot to include. Sorry about that. I have made a sandbox. Would really appreciate if you could look at the question again

Comment: @tonitone120 — That doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin. Although it might not be significant to answering my question, presumably the new invoking of Function Component (FC) happens after `useEffect` is finished, here?

Comment: I'm really not sure of the timing. The function you pass *to* `useEffect` will be completely defined by then though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet logging the `color` state value at various times and also showing the effect of cleaning up in the return of the useEffect. It only serves to illustrate the timeline that Quentin laid out in their answer.

```js
const App = ()=>{
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState("red");
  
  console.log('outside: ', color);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setColor("blue");
    console.log('inside: ', color);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('inside-timed: ', color);
    }, 5000)
    
    // the cleaned-up timer won't fire
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('timer: ', color);
    }, 5000)

    return (clearTimeout(timer));
  },[])
  
 return (
  <div style={{backgroundColor: color, width: '40px', height: '40px'}} ></div>
 )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```