# How is setColor() referencing the most recent color variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export default function App() {
  let [color, setColor] = useState("red");

  useEffect(() => {
    setColor("blue");
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(color);
      setColor("purple");
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  function revealColor() {
    console.log(color);
  }
  return <button onClick={revealColor}>Click after 1 second to reveal color</button>
}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-gates-zb6b8?file=/src/App.js)

Following this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65220922/callback-doesnt-receive-the-updated-version-of-state-even-when-it-fires-well-af/65221568#65221568) I understand that `setTimeout`'s callback references the first `color` variable (red). Somehow though its `setColor` manages to change the most recent `color` variable (as evidenced by clicking the button which logs "purple"). How is this so? I thought `setColor` would similarly reference the old `setColor` variable.

P.S. by 'old', I'm referring to the fact that the `setColor("blue");` re-executes the whole component which returns a new `color` variable/function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setColor` is a function which changes the `color` in the state. It doesn't *directly* change the `color` variable.

Every time the state changes the `App` function reruns.

So when it runs for the first time it calls `useState("red")`, discovers there is no existing state, sets the state to `"red"` then assigns the state (`"red"`) to `color`. The DOM is updated with the result.

`setColor("blue");` changes the state to `"blue"` which causes `App` to run again. There is already a state so `color` is set to `"blue"`. It isn't initialized with `"red"`. The DOM is updated with the result.

A second later, the timeout resolves and `setColor("purple");` sets the colour in the state to `"purple"` which causes `App` to run **again**. There is already a state so `color` is set to `"purple"`.

Each time the DOM is updated it has a new `revealColor` function passed to `onClick` which has closed over the `color` variable from the most recent invoke of `App`.

---

Meanwhile, the function you pass to `useEffect` only runs **once** (because you passed `[]` as the second argument) so the `color` variable it has closed over is the original and you get `"red"` logged there.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you didn't include `color` in the dependency array of `useEffect`. Because of that, `useEffect` doesn't know that the `color` has changed. If you include it in the dependency array, then `useEffect` will fire whenever `color` is changed. Therefore, you can see `blue` when you log it.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setColor("blue");
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(color);
      setColor("purple");
    }, 1000);
  }, [color]); // <- dependency array
```